Rewiring strategies to obtain networks with desired clustering coefficient and average path length
Note: this question was originally posted in the programming StackExchange, but as it is more of a conceptual/mathematical question, I am now posting it here.
There have been a few questions (and subsequent answers) regarding the generation of connected networks (graphs) with fixed edge density (fixed no of edges), see e.g., here and here.
These are mostly based on the methods put forward by Bansal et al. (2009). Yet, for my specific problem I am interested in generating networks with a desired global clustering coefficient and a desired average path length. The global clustering coefficient is essentially the no. of triangles divided by the no. of all triplets, and the average path length here is the average (shortest) distance between each nodes.
Note that these are both expensive to compute in general.
If possible, I would like to fix the average path length while being able to 'tune' the clustering coefficient to be (close to a) desired value, or vice versa.
I have already explored preferential attachment schemes, which often result in no clustering (i.e., no triangles, which one can see for example for the Barabasi-Albert with $m=1$), yet I cannot find preferential attachment schemes that result in a desired, arbitrary global clustering coefficient.
I can of course resort to multivariate Simulated Annealing (SA) schemes, that in principle should allow me to search for graphs with any desired structure, however as computing the average path length is expensive, my (naive) implementations already take substantial time for small networks with ~100 nodes. Ideally, I would like to generate many networks with, say, ~1000 nodes, so finding these graphs should of course not take too much time.
Outside of SA, are there known algorithms and/or (edge) rewiring procedures that can change either the global clustering coefficient or the average path length, but not both? Alternatively, if SA is the only option, is there a way to drastically reduce the computation of the global clustering coefficient and/or the average path length such that it can be incrementally updated, thereby allowing the SA to run for more iterations?
